# Creating unmodifiableSet from unmodifiableSet

Tags: java, collections, immutability

[Collections.unmodifiableSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet%28java.util.Set%29) allows me to create an unmodifiable view of a set. I'm assuming this is done by wrapping the provided set. Will there be any performance problem(s) if unmodifiable sets are created from already unmodifiable sets?

e.g.

```
Set<String> set = Collections.unmodifiableSet(Collections.unmodifiableSet(Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<String>())));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collections.unmodifiableSet - just wraps a set with UnmodifiableSet instance, which just proxies all method invocation. Additional finite method invocation sequence is not a subject of performance consideration, sure if you are not talking about thousands of wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

The method signature is:

```
public static <T> Set<T> unmodifiableSet(Set<? extends T> s) {
    return new UnmodifiableSet<T>(s);
}
```

in the class `Collections`. Which returns a new instance of object `UnmodifiableSet`. Now this class is inner static class:

```
static class UnmodifiableSet<E> extends UnmodifiableCollection<E> implements Set<E>, Serializable
```

In the class `UnmodifiableCollection` the methods like `add`, `remove`, `addAll` etc `throws UnsupportedOperationException`. That is why it is `Unmodifiable`.

Now if you instantiate thousands time a collection of course it would be issue.